# Tensorflow argmax() for TFLearn?

Tags: python, mnist, tflearn

I used the *mnist* data set of `tflearn` to predict handwritten digits.

Everything works, but I have the labels as *one_hot*. Is there a function in `tflearn`, which does the same as `argmax()` in Tensorflow?

Comment: Note sure how the tensor is formatted, but could you use `np.argmax(tensor)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by doing this:

```
pred = model.predict(test_data)

print([ np.where(r==1)[0][0] for r in np.round(pred) ])
```

Best.